Volume of a bowl using the Shell Method
A bowl has a shape that can be generated by revolving the graph of $ y=\frac{x^2}{2} $ between $ y=0 $ and $ y=5 $ about the $y$-axis.
(a) Find the volume of the bowl.
(b) If we fill the bowl with water at a constant rate of 3 cubic units per second, how fast will the water level in the bowl be rising when the water is 4 units deep?
The solution uses the washer/disk method. When I first tried this problem, my first approach was to use the Shell Method, but I couldn't figure out why my approach was wrong. Here is my solution:
(a) By the Shell Method,
$$
V=2\pi \int_0^\sqrt{10}x\left(5-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx = 25\pi
$$
(b) Since $ y=\frac{x^2}{2} $, when $ y=4 $, $ x=2\sqrt{2} $
$$
\frac{dV}{dx}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[2\pi \int_0^xu\left(5-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)du\right]=2\pi\left(5x-\frac{x^3}{2}\right) = 10\pi x - \pi x^3
$$
Then,
$$ 
\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\dfrac{dV}{dt}}{\dfrac{dV}{dx}}=\dfrac{3}{10\pi x - \pi x^3}
$$
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x\left(\dfrac{3}{10\pi x - \pi x^3}\right) = \dfrac{3}{10\pi - \pi x^2}
$$
Plug in $x=2\sqrt{2}$, $ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{3}{2\pi} $ unit/sec
Can someone point out my mistake, and show me how to find the correct answer, which is $\dfrac{3}{8\pi}$unit/sec, using the Shell Method?

We simply have that, at $y=4$ and at a constant rate of $1$ cubic units per second
$$dV = \pi(2\sqrt 2)^2 dh \implies \frac{dh}{dV}=\frac{1}{8\pi}$$
therefore, at a constant rate of $3$ cubic units per second, the rising rate of the water is $\frac{3}{8\pi}$.

Your evaluation by shell method is uncorrect, indeed we should evaluate
$$V(x)=2\pi \int_0^{x}u\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{u^2}{2}\right)du=\frac{\pi x^4}4 \implies \frac{dV}{dx}=\pi x^3$$
therefore
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x\dfrac{3}{\pi x^3} = \dfrac{3}{\pi x^2}$$
which leads to the correct answer.
